# ora-39087 directory name is invalid

Tags: oracle, datapump

I have created a Database in oracle 19c with the following command

```
dbca -silent -createDatabase                                                   \
     -templateName General_Purpose.dbc                                         \
     -gdbname CDB1  -sid  CDB1 -responseFile NO_VALUE         \
     -characterSet AL32UTF8                                                    \
     -sysPassword SysPassword1                                                 \
     -systemPassword SysPassword1                                              \
     -createAsContainerDatabase true                                           \
     -numberOfPDBs 1                                                           \
     -pdbName PDB1                                                      \
     -pdbAdminPassword PdbPassword1                                            \
     -databaseType MULTIPURPOSE                                                \
     -memoryMgmtType auto_sga                                                  \
     -totalMemory 2000                                                         \
     -storageType FS                                                           \
     -datafileDestination "${DATA_DIR}"                                        \
     -redoLogFileSize 50                                                       \
     -emConfiguration NONE                                                     \
     -ignorePreReqs
```

I am trying to do a data pump export of pluggable database(PDB1) with the following commands

```
# mkdir -p /u02/dp_exp_dir
# chown oracle:oinstall /u02/dp_exp_dir
# chmod 775 /u02/dp_exp_dir

sqlplus / as sysdba
create directory datapump as '/u02/dp_exp_dir';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY datapump TO system;

# expdp system/SysPassword1@PDB1 full=Y directory=datapump \
dumpfile=DB10G.dmp logfile=expdpDB10G.log
```

I get the following message:

```
ora-39002 invalid operation
ora-39070 unable to open the log file
ora-39087 directory name DATAPUMP is invalid
```

Comment: sqlplus / as sysdba takes you to the root-container. Navigate to the PDB1 before you create the datapump directory object: "alter session set container=PDB1;"

Comment: Does the directory '/u02/dp_exp_dir' actully exist?  the CREATE DIRECTORY command only creates the directory object within the database.  It _does not_ create the actual directory on the OS file system.

Comment: @BjarteBrandt, you're right, I had to enter the PDB. Thanks